# Unwrap "a" tag from image, without losing content

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I wanted to remove 'a' tag (link) from all the images found. Hence for performance I made a list of all images in the html and look for wrapping a tag and simply remove the link.

I am using BeautifulSoup and not sure what I am doing wrong, instead of removing the a tag it is removing the inside content.

**This is what I did**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div> <a href="http://somelink"><img src="http://imgsrc.jpg" /></a> <a href="http://somelink2"><img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg /></a>"  '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    print 'THIS IS THE BEGINING /////////////// '
    #print img.find_parent('a').unwrap()
    print img.parent.unwrap()
```

**This gives me following output**

```
> >> print img.parent() 
<a href="http://somelink"><img src="http://imgsrc.jpg" /></a> 
<a href="http://somelink2"><img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg /></a>

> >> print img.parent.unwrap() 
<a href="http://somelink"></a> 
<a href="http://somelink2"></a>
```

I have tried `replaceWith` and `replaceWithChildren` but not working when I use `object.parent` or `findParent`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Its been just few weeks since I started python.

Comment: The code you posted can't have produced that output - that looks like output from a command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unwrap()` function *returns the tag that has been removed*. The tree itself has been properly modified. Quoting from the [`unwrap()` documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap):

> Like `replace_with()`, `unwrap()` returns the tag that was replaced.

In other words: it works correctly! Print the *new* parent of `img` instead of the return value of `unwrap()` to see that the `<a>` tags have indeed been removed:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<div> <a href="http://somelink"><img src="http://imgsrc.jpg" /></a> <a href="http://somelink2"><img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg /></a>"  '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for img in soup.find_all('img'):
...     img.parent.unwrap()
...     print img.parent
... 
<a href="http://somelink"></a>
<div> <img src="http://imgsrc.jpg"/> <a href="http://somelink2"><img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;"/></a></div>
<a href="http://somelink2"></a>
<div> <img src="http://imgsrc.jpg"/> <img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;"/></div>
```

Here python echoes the `img.parent.unwrap()` return value, followed by the output of the `print` statement showing the parent of the `<img>` tag is now the `<div>` tag. The first print shows the *other* `<img>` tag still wrapped, the second print shows them both as direct children of the `<div>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot , I did not realize .unwrap() by default prints the value, when you look inside terminal I was not able to figure out how I was getting that. Thanks again for explaining so well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what output you are looking for. Is this it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div> <a href="http://somelink"><img src="http://imgsrc.jpg" /></a> <a href="http://somelink2"><img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg" /></a>  '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    img.parent.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

yields

```
<html><body><div> <img src="http://imgsrc.jpg"/> <img src="http://imgsrc2.jpg"/></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much with Python, but it looks like [unwrap](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) returns the HTML that was removed, and not the img tag you're looking for. Try calling `soup.prettify()` and see if the link was removed after all.